# Multiple user login via xrdp with separate session: How to do that?

Tags: 13.10, xrdp, remote-x-session, remote-login

I have been trying to set up a RDP connection using xrdp and have been having significant trouble getting a working configuration.

When a user logs on, I need it to connect with a new session.
So workflow is like my Ubuntu machine has three users, say lin1 ,lin2 ,lin3. Every time a user connects remotely to my Ubuntu machine, he must connect with new session.

Say if first user connect he must logged in to lin1 user and if second user connect at same, he must logged in with lin2 user and so on. So that each user can maintain there separate session, and also multiple user can log in at same time.

What changes to the default configuration do I need to make in order for this to work?

For details refer this. I need to implement something like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281262) in linux

Answer (score 1):

I have googled a bit for your question.... and I have found some info about what you wanna do at this link http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

To summarize

By default, if a user connect remotely via xrdp, each user will get a different session. the problem you will encounter with Ubuntu and xrdp is indeed that each time a user connect; it will open a new session

To fix this issue; you have to tweak your xrdp installation + explain to your users how to reconnect to the session

Edit the /ect/xrdp/xrdp.ini file 
under section [xrdp1] 
replace the line 
port=-1 
with the following line 
port=ask-1

This change will add an additional field in your xrdp login screen where you can specify the port. 
The first time the user connects, he should accept the default (i.e. -1), the next time he connects in order to reconnect to the same session, the user needs to provide the port used during the first connection.  This information can be found in the login process dialog box when performing the first connection

You might wanna have a look at the following link which explain the process quite well

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305 - Check the section Reconnecting to an existing session in the post.

Hope this is helpful to you

Note also that if you are using ubuntu 13.10, you will need to install an alternate desktop (other than unity or gnome).

See ya